# rails performance test -run one test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testunit

I have couple performance tests in my rails app

which resides in test/performance/some_file.rb
so file contain couple methods. I need run only one to get good logs

inside file I have couple test_* methods.

Is there any way to run only one performance test?
I'm  execute:

```
 rake test:benchmark TESTOPTS="--name=test_with_pet_care_job"
```

and looks like my test started but it freeze for some reason
how can I run only one test?

here is source files:

## test/performance/registrations/parent_full_test.rb

```
require './test/test_helper'
require 'rails/performance_test_help'
require 'benchmark_test_helper'
require './test/performance/registrations/logging_methods'

module Registration
  class ParentFullTest < ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest
    attr_reader :parent_data

    include Registrations::LoggingMethods

    def test_with_pet_care_job
      registration_step '01 Member should be created' do
        post registration_submit_path, parent_data[:base_info]
      end

      registration_step '02 Job should be posted' do
        post registration_submit_path, parent_data[:petcare_job]
      end
    end

    def test_with_companion_care_job
      registration_step '01 Member should be created' do
        post registration_submit_path, parent_data[:base_info]
      end

      registration_step '02 Job should be posted' do
        post registration_submit_path, parent_data[:companion_care_job]
      end
   end

   def setup
     refresh_member_data
     delete logout_path

     write_to_log("performance test started")
   end

   def teardown
     Account::Member.last.profile.destroy # to clean mongo data
   end


   private

   def refresh_member_data
     @parent_data = BenchmarkTestHelper.yaml_data(data_file)
   end

   def data_file
     File.join(File.expand_path('..' ,__FILE__), 'data/parent.yml.erb')
   end
 end
```

end

## test/performance/registrations/logging_methods.rb

```
module Registrations
  module LoggingMethods

    def registration_step(step_name)
      before_count = Profile::MemberActivity.count
      write_to_log(step_name + ' started')
      yield
      write_to_log(step_name + ' finished')
      assert_equal Profile::MemberActivity.count, before_count+1, step_name
    end

    def write_to_log(message)
      Rails.logger.debug message
    end
end
```

## test/benchmark_test_helper.rb

```
require 'yaml'

module BenchmarkTestHelper
  class << self
    def yaml_data(file_name)
      YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(file_name)).result).with_indifferent_access
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby -I test test/performance/some_file.rb --name=test_with_pet_care_job
```

Comment: In Rails 4, the command will be: rails -f test test/performance/some_file.rb --name=test_with_pet_care_job

Comment: I think it's the same command behind the curtain. anyway I try run it like you suggest - result is the same. looks like a bug. let me post source code

Comment: Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Loaded suite test/performance/registrations/parent_full_test
Started
Registration::ParentFullTest#test_with_babysitter_job (718 ms warmup)
        process_time: 729 ms

and thats it